# How to set up gateway of public network in vagrant

Tags: networking, virtualbox, vagrant, centos6, gateway

I am setting up my Virtualbox Centos VM with vagrant. I am setting up with a public network.

```
config.vm.network :public_network, ip: "10.135.15.137"
```

How do I setup the GATEWAY along with this?

Answer (score 5):

According to the (new) documentation, setting up a gateway, can be done by instructing the following, inside the Vagrantfile:

```
# default router
config.vm.provision "shell",
  run: "always",
  inline: "route add default gw 192.168.0.1"
```

Read the complete example titled *Default Router* at http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/public_network.html.

Comment: You also might want to specify which network interface you want: `sudo route add default gw 10.0.0.1 eth1`

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Vagrant doesn't support this at the moment.

But there are requests for adding it, for example [GH-2832](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/2832) and [GH-2389](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/2389). The latter one also has some shell provisioner examples you could use to work around it.

Answer (score 2):

Vagrant 2.0.1 has a configuration option for this which is explained in the documentation:

[Vagrant → Networking → Public Networks → Using the DHCP Assigned Default Route](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/public_network.html#using-the-dhcp-assigned-default-route)

For your convenience, here is the relevant section (retrieved 2018-05-15):

> #### Using the DHCP Assigned Default Route
>
> Some cases require the DHCP
>   assigned default route to be untouched. In these cases one may specify
>   the use_dhcp_assigned_default_route option. As an example:
>
> ```
> Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
>   config.vm.network "public_network",
>    use_dhcp_assigned_default_route: true
> end
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a solution for ubuntu with netplan to set the default gateway to the public network. persistent across reboots.

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
  cat <<EOF >> /etc/netplan/60-override.yaml
  ---
  network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
      eth0:
        dhcp4: yes
        dhcp4-overrides:
          use-routes: false
      eth1:
        dhcp4: true
   EOF
   netplan apply
   sleep 5
 SHELL
```